# SQLite AVG() with LEFT JOIN not returning all rows

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I'm having a problem with a rating system.

When there is no matches in the `LEFT JOIN` it dosnt return the row at all when using `AVG()`.

This is returning NULL if there is no results in join.

```
SELECT op_id,
       ...,
       rating_stars
```

But this removes the row.

```
SELECT op_id,
       ...,
       AVG(rating_stars)
```

This is my last attempt:

```
SELECT op_id,
       op_img,
       op_title,
       op_worktime,
       op_cookingtime,
       CASE rating_stars WHEN null THEN 0 ELSE AVG(rating_stars) END
FROM 
 opskrifter
LEFT JOIN 
  rating 
ON 
  rating.fk_op_id = opskrifter.op_id
WHERE 
  fk_type_id=1 
ORDER BY 
  op_id DESC
```

I need all the results and if it hasnt been rated yet it should just return 0 like this:

```
ID        | RATING
--- 1 --- | ---  0  ---
--- 2 --- | ---  4  ---
--- 3 --- | ---  0  ---
```

But the above SQL returns this:

```
ID        | RATING
--- 2 --- | ---  4  ---
```

I'm pretty sure I've done this in MySQL, with no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have `GROUP BY` clause,

```
SELECT...
FROM...
WHERE...
GROUP BY op_id,
       op_img,
       op_title,
       op_worktime,
       op_cookingtime
```

Comment: *can you post sample records along with your question?*

Comment: is the output of this query correct? see here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0fda4/1